# Gdebi problem on downloading Sogou

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, gdebi

I am downloading Sogou for my PC, but I found that I can't, and I downloaded `gdebi`. Finally, it showed me this:

[image]

```
Dependency is not satisfiable: fonts-droid
```

Comment: i guess i havent got that.

Comment: Please edit your question to include Ubuntu version. ..... `fonts-droid` : http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fonts-droid&searchon=names

Answer (score 1):

Example, Ubuntu 16.04 : `fonts-droid` http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-android/fonts-droid_4.4.4r2-6ubuntu1_all.deb

`cd Downloads/ && sudo gdebi ./fonts-droid_4.4.4r2-6ubuntu1_all.deb`